# WPF, C# Сортировка по выбранному объекту из ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq

у меня есть база данных, там перечислены районы, хочу сделать сортировку по выбранному району

выгружаю данные из таблицы районы в combobbox:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cmbDisctrictList.ItemsSource = AppData.db.Disctrict.Select(item => item.Title).ToList();
    }
```

пишу код для сортировки:

```
    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListData.ItemsSource = AppData.db.SimATCAbonent.Where(item => item.ATC.CityDisctict.Disctrict.Title == (cmbDisctrictList.SelectedItem)).ToList();
    }
```

выдает на рандом данные

Comment: А если `cmbDisctrictList.SelectedItem` заменить на `e.AddedItems[0]`? Сдается мне, что событие отрабатывает раньше, чем `SelectedItem` меняется. И лучше бы вы привязки данных использовали, а не обработчики, которые толком подходят только к Winforms.

Comment: @aepot, не-а, не сработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var selectedType = cmbType.SelectedItem as Model.Type;
        cmbSubType.ItemsSource = AppData.db.SubType.Where(i => i.IDType == selectedType.ID).ToList();
```